# What is the entity_id in square webhooks for refunds?

Tags: square-connect

I read https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/webhooks-in-the-square-connect-api-d4d38c4b4d9f, which implies that the webhook entity_id will be a payment_id.  If I have a refund for a single tender order, the payment_id and the entity_id of the webhook match.  However, when I refund that payment to multiple tenders, the id in the webhook is the tender id for the first tender and I only get one webhook.  The payment_id that gets returned from the payments api is different.

Can someone please verify what entity_id is here?  Is it always the tender_id of the first tender?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read the [webhook documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=webhook#webhooks-overview) as well. It will always be a `payment_id` that you can use the [Retrieve Payment](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=webhook#get-paymentid) endpoint to get more information from.

Comment: The issue is that for multi-tender refunds instead of the overall payment id, I'm getting the id associated with the tender not the larger payment.  Will it always be that way?  If I have an order with three tenders and I refund to two tenders what id will be in the webhook? Will it be the larger payment id or one of the tender ids?  The major issue is that I need to check for duplication but it's very difficult to know what to check unless what's getting sent in the entity_id for this payment_updated webhook is consistent.

Comment: What is your use case? Since square's webhooks don't retry, you might want to consider polling instead.

Comment: we wanted to use the webhooks for payments and refunds.  We had issues with polling because sometimes the transaction data wasn't fully complete so relying on the webhooks is a bit better because they only get sent after the transaction is completed. We also as much as possible need to tie refunds to items that got refunded and are relying on the inventory count for that which can change so we want to do that asap. It's not an ideal solution but necessary for our own data models.

Comment: I think that polling might still be better for you, are you using the inventory APIs?

Comment: Yes we are using the inventory apis.  I think I'm going to go with a combination of webhooks and polling.  Also, after testing many things, it looks like the payment_updated webhook for refunds always returns the payment_id that belongs to one of the tenders that is part of the refund.